# callback on ajax for setting variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling a callback function after ajax call as shown below.

```js
 var mypage= {};
 var mypagebox = {
   somefunction: function() {
     var self = this;
     self.createID(obj, function(resp) {
       if (resp.ERRORSTATUS == 0) {
         
         mypage.newID = resp.newID;
         console.log("pooped in array ");
         console.log(mypage.newID);
       }
       console.log("outside if ");
       console.log(newID.newID);
     });
     console.log("outside scope ");
     console.log(mypage.newID);
   },
   createID: function(_obj, callback) {
     $.ajax({
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         'dataType': "json"
       },
       data: {
         //Some data
       },
       url: "/url"
     }).done(function(res, d) {
       callback(JSON.parse(res));
     });
   }
 };
```

So when mypagebox.somefunction is called, I get the following output in console.

```
outside scope 
 []
 outside total scope
 []
 pooped in array 
 [Object]
 outside if 
 [Object]
```

When I try to use mypage.newID in another method of mypagebox, i get null. How can i fix this.

Comment: do not use `mypage.newID` before `function(resp) { ... }` executes

Answer (score 0):

Your code and explanation not be help our. You can organized someFunction(), What is the newID object? console.log(newID.newID) ??

I suggestion, you should add to project on jsfiddle platform.